# How to sync a box2d body or a texture with music? LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i have a dynamic body and a texture with a red circle image
what i want is the more beat got the song the more higher jumps the dynamic body
or the more bigger become the texture and when the music calm again the circe became smaller

Answer (score 1):

The libGDX API doesn't give you any way to tell what the "beat" or the "volume" of the music is at any particular point in time. You would likely have to create your own library that can access this data from the music, or fake it by creating a text file that says "At this point in the song, the beat is X and at this point it is Y", and then use the text file to time the size of your texture.